Issues with converting FFmpeg video from HEV1 to HVC1
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -tag:v hvc1 out.mp4

I used FFmpeg to transcode the videos, but some of the transcoded videos were black screens with audio but no visuals.
视频一的视频信息 (Video Information of Video I)



视频二的视频信息 (Video Information of Video II)



By using ffmpeg -i video.mp4 to view the video information, it was found that the information for both videos is consistent.
However, the screen in figure 1 displays a black screen after transcoding, whereas figure 2 functions normally after transcoding.
